# array empty on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn on making my first dynamic loader from scratch with jQuery (for learning purpose) here is where I got stuck:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.learningdynamicloader= function(){
     var js = [];
     var css = [];
     console.log(js,css);
};
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.learningdynamicloader(function(){
        js = ['jquery','test'];
        css = ['css','test'];
    });
});
</script>
```

My firebug log `js` and `css` returns nothing, it seems that there is a problem. After I Google is there any diffrence between `js = ['values']` and `js : ['values']` ?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing the arrays as arguments rather than declaring them locally:

```
jQuery.learningdynamicloader= function(js, css){
    console.log(js,css);
};
```

And then:

```
var js = ['jquery','test'];
var css = ['css','test'];
$.learningdynamicloader(js, css);
```

Edit: I think that what you are after is something like this though:

```
jQuery.learningdynamicloader= function(params){
    console.log(params["js"], params["css"]);
};
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.learningdynamicloader({ "js": ['jquery','test'], "css": ['css','test'] });
});
```

This will pass complex object to your function, with two properties, each array of its own.

Comment: this work great!, yeah im aware about passing them as arguments, but its better on readability, as most of plugin example use something like this. just following some existing jquery function like http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ they can have local vars, how do they achieve this ?

Comment: Can you show an example of code that does this? I'm not sure what you're after.

Comment: Cheers, regarding what you said about `.ajax()` see my edit, this is pretty similar, passing whole bunch of properties as one complex object  to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say this go back and read into javascript, you cant overide a function by passing it a function as an argument

```
jQuery.learningdynamicloader= function(fn){
     js = [];
     css = [];
     fn();
     console.log(js,css);
};
```

The same can be done like so this one will use the function private scope the top one will use the window scope

```
jQuery.learningdynamicloader= function(fn){
         var js = [];
         var css = [];
         fn(js, css);
         console.log(js,css);
    };
```